# Logical indexing in Numpy with two indices as in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, indexing

How do I replicate this indexing done in MATLAB with Numpy?

```
X=magic(5);
M=[0,0,1,2,1];
X(M==0,M==2)
```

that returns:

```
ans =
  8
 14
```

I've found that doing this in Numpy is not correct, since it does not give me the same results..

```
X = np.matrix([[17, 24,  1,  8, 15],
        [23,  5,  7, 14, 16],
        [ 4,  6, 13, 20, 22],
        [10, 12, 19, 21,  3],
        [11, 18, 25,  2,  9]])

M=array([0,0,1,2,1])
X.take([M==0]).take([M==2], axis=1)
```

since I get:

```
 matrix([[24, 24, 24, 24, 24]])
```

What is the correct way to logically index with two indices in numpy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general there are two ways to interpret `X[a, b]` when both a and b are arrays (vectors in matlab), "inner-style" indexing or "outer-style" indexing.

The designers of matlab chose "outer-style" indexing and the designers of numpy chose inner-style indexing. To do "outer-style" indexing in numpy one can use:

```
X[np.ix_(a, b)]
# This is roughly equal to matlab's
X(a, b)
```

for completness you can do "inner-style" indexing in matlab by doing:

```
X(sub2ind(size(X), a, b))
# This is roughly equal to numpy's
X[a, b]
```

In short, try `X[np.ix_(M == 0, M == 1)]`.