# Logical indices in numpy throwing exception

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to write some code that uses logical numpy arrays to index a larger array, similar to how MATLAB allows array indexing with logical arrays.

```
import numpy as np
m = 4
n = 4
unCov = np.random.randint(10, size = (m,n) )
rowCov = np.zeros( m, dtype = bool )
colCov = np.ones( n, dtype = bool )
>>> unCov[rowCov, rowCov] 
[]  # as expected
>>> unCov[colCov, colCov]
[0 8 3 3]  # diagonal values of unCov, as expected
>>> unCov[rowCov, colCov]
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

For this last evaluation, I expected an empty array, similar to what MATLAB returns.  I'd rather not have to check rowCov/colCov for True elements prior to indexing.  Why is this happening, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Umm...matlab returns the full matrix in the latter case, not the diagonal values. Isn't that right?

Comment: @Andras Oh, good point, you are correct!  Sorry, I was not focusing on that aspect of the MATLAB comparison.  I guess numpy and MATLAB are more different than I realized in this aspect.

Comment: Take a look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357622/logical-indexing-in-numpy-with-two-indices-as-in-matlab/22366062#22366062) I think it answers your question.

Comment: @Bi Rico: Yes, thank you!  That works just how I want it to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, numpy will translate your 2d logical indices to actual index vectors: `arr[[True,False],[False,True]]` would become `arr[0,1]` for an `ndarray` of shape `(2,2)`. However, in your last case the second index array is full `False`, hence it corresponds to an index array of length 0. This is paired with the other full `True` index vector, corresponding to an index array of length 4.

From [the **numpy** manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays):

> If the index arrays do not have the same shape, there is an attempt to
>   broadcast them to the same shape. If they cannot be broadcast to the
>   same shape, an exception is raised:

In your case, the error is exactly due to this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1411-28e41e233472> in <module>()
----> 1 unCov[colCov,rowCov]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (0,)
```

MATLAB, on the other hand, automatically returns an empty array if the index array is empty along any given dimension.

---

This actually highlights a fundamental difference between the logical indexing in MATLAB and numpy. In MATLAB, vectors in subscript indexing always slice out a subarray. That is, both

```
arr([1,2],[1,2])
```

and

```
arr([true,true],[true,true])
```

will return the `2 x 2` submatrix of the matrix `arr`. If the logical index vectors are shorter than the given dimension of the array, the missing indexing elements are assumed to be `false`. Fun fact: the index vector can also be *longer* than the given dimension, as long as the excess elements are all `false`. So the above is also equivalent to

```
arr([true,true,false,false],[true,true])
```

and

```
arr([true,true,false,false,false,false,false],[true,true])
```

for a `4 x 4` array (for the sake of argument).

In numpy, however, indexing with boolean-valued numpy `arrays` in this way will try to extract a vector. Furthermore, the boolean index vectors should be the same length as the dimension they are indexing into. In your `4 x 4` example,

```
unCov[np.array([True,True]),np.array([True,True])]
```

and

```
unCov[np.array([True,True,False,False,False]),np.array([True,True,False,False,False])]
```

both return the *two first diagonal elements*, so not a submatrix but rather a vector. Furthermore, they also give the less-then-encouraging warning along the lines of

```
/usr/bin/ipython:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5
```

So, in numpy, your logical indexing vectors should be the same length as the corresponding dimensions of the `ndarray`. And then what I wrote above holds true: the logical values are translated into indices, and the result is expected to be a vector. The length of this vector is the number of `True` elements in every index vector, so if your boolean index vectors have a different number of `True` elements, then the referencing doesn't make sense, and you get the error that you get.

Comment: I was basically going to write this. +1.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation...very good info!  It seems slightly non-Pythonic that you cannot perform general indexing like unCov[rowCov, colCov] without first checkiing if one of the arrays is all False.  Bummer.